# angularjs interceptor $broadcast doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-authentication

I'm playing around with the code of
http://ngmodules.org/modules/http-auth-interceptor
and I'm wondering why

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('loginRequired');
```

doesn't trigger the alert in the controller

```
$scope.$on('loginRequired',function() {
    alert('loginRequired');   
});
```

The code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myModule">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="content" class="ng-view"></div>
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var buffer = angular.module('http-auth-interceptor-buffer', []);
        buffer.factory('httpBuffer',  function($injector) {
            var buffer = [];
            var $http;

            function retryHttpRequest(config, deferred) {
                function successCallback(response) {
                    deferred.resolve(response);
                }
                function errorCallback(response) {
                    deferred.reject(response);
                }
                $http = $http || $injector.get('$http');
                $http(config).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
            }

            return {

                append: function(config, deferred) {
                    buffer.push({
                        config: config,
                        deferred: deferred
                    });
                },

                retryAll: function(updater) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < buffer.length; ++i) {
                        retryHttpRequest(updater(buffer[i].config), buffer[i].deferred);
                    }
                    buffer = [];
                }
            };
        });

        var app = angular.module('myModule', ['http-auth-interceptor-buffer']);
        app.config(function($httpProvider,$routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
            $httpProvider.interceptors.push('securityInterceptor');
            $routeProvider.
            when('/one',{
                controller: 'OneCtrl',
                /*resolve: {
                    my: function(Data) {
                        return Data.getData();
                    }
                },*/
                templateUrl: './_one.html'
            }).
            when('/two', {
                controller: 'TwoCtrl',
                templateUrl:'./_two.html'
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/one'
            });
        });

        app.controller('OneCtrl',function($scope,Data) {
            $scope.my = Data.getData();
            $scope.$on('loginRequired',function() {
                alert('loginRequired');   
            });
        });

        app.controller('TwoCtrl',function($scope) {

        });

        app.factory('Data', function($http,$q) {
            return {
                getData : function() {
                    var deferred = $q.defer();
                    var promise = $http.get('./security.php').success(function (response) {
                        deferred.resolve(response);
                    });

                    // Return the promise to the controller
                    return deferred.promise; 
                }
            }
        });

        app.factory('securityInterceptor', function($q, $rootScope,httpBuffer) {
            return {
                request: function(config) {
                    return config || $q.when(config);
                },

                requestError: function(rejection) {
                },

                response: function(response) {
                    return response || $q.when(response);
                },

                responseError: function(rejection) {
                    if(rejection.status === 401) {
                        var deferred = $q.defer();
                        httpBuffer.append(rejection.config, deferred);
                        $rootScope.$broadcast('loginRequired');
                        return deferred.promise;
                    }

                    return $q.reject(rejection);
                }
            };
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE**

security.php

```
<?php
header('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized');
$data = 'MyTets';

echo json_encode($data);
```

What's the trouble ?

Comment: Did you check if the event is spread before the setting of the listner?

Comment: In OneCtrl calling Data.getData(); get me from the server a 401 status  I updated my post

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code by putting

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('loginRequired');
```

in securityInterceptor

```
response: function(response) {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('loginRequired');
    return response || $q.when(response);
},
```

had problem to simulate the response of the php file. Your code and the events are working well. It should come from your php file which didn't return 401 right?

here is a plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/MQTa60jYGomukQHcIdOl?p=preview)